# How do I calculate true positive, true negative, false positive, and false negative

Tags: analytics, prediction, confusion-matrix, predictionio

Actually I am working on `specificity` and `sensitivity`. I have to calculate confusion matrix. but I don't know how to calculate. Output of prediction IO model is categorized into 3 categories like positive, negative and neutral. Can any one tell me how to calculate confusion matrix when my output have more than 2 classes. It may be silly question, so please guide me how I can achieve my goal.

```
Sensitivity = ( no of true positive)/ ((no of true positive)+(no of false negative))
```

or

```
Sensitivity = ( no of true positive)/ ((no of true positive)+(no of false negative)+(no of false neutral))
```

which should I have to used for sensitivity

Thanks.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51296/how-to-calculate-precision-and-recall-for-multiclass-classification-using-confus

Comment: https://pytech-solution.blogspot.com/2019/06/evaluation-metrices-for-machine.html you can refer to this blog to understand the evaluation metrics and related terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terms "positive" and "negative" only make sense with a binomial classifier -- a true positive is when you get a correct "yes, this belongs here" and a true negative when you correctly get "no, this doesn't belong to the category".  So there can only be two categories, or actually just one, and its complement.  Everything which doesn't belong in the category is a negative.  Then the confusion matrix looks like this:

```
   P   N
P  7   3
N  2   9
```

So in this example, you have 7 true positives and 9 true negatives.  Where the classifier returned positive for negative samples, you have 2 false positives; similarly, there are 3 false negatives.

This can be generalized to a multinomial confusion matrix, though.  Just add more cells to the matrix to make room for every combination.

```
    A    B    C
A   7    6    2
B   -   19    1
C   3    9    7
```

Across, you have the outcome from your classifier.  Down, you have the actual category of each sample.  So you have 7 "true A", 19 "true B", and 7 "true C" across the diagonal, and the others are confused -- 1 "false C" which should have been a B instead, 9 "false B" which should have been C instead, etc.

Comment: see the updated question. which one is right formula for sensitivity

Comment: Quick googling suggests that this is not a well-established concept.  You can do "cat" vs "not cat" for each category as suggested [here](http://www.columbia.edu/~so33/SusDev/Lecture_10.pdf) but at this point, maybe ask your professor.

Comment: Changing the question after you get answers is not good form here.  Perhaps you should simply accept this answer and post a new question with your new question.  This is getting dangerously outside the topic of programming questions, though; perhaps try https://stats.stackexchange.com/ instead (not intimately familiar with their guidelines so check them first).

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity) seems to concur -- it says specifically these are for binary classification.

Comment: I stuck with formula of sensitivity as per your answer about confusion matrix. that's why I added some more in my question.